# Can I add request parameter to SockJs constructor so that it can be send to server

Tags: spring-websocket, sockjs

I initialize my SockJs URL as

```
var protocols = ['xhr-polling', 'xdr-polling',  'xdr-streaming', 'xhr-streaming'];
var options = {protocols_whitelist: protocols, debug: true,server:tets};
_ws = new SockJS(url, null, options);
```

I want to send out a request parameter , for example somesite/sockjs/info?someparam=tets"

Is it possible? Documentation [of SockJs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) refers that options is map which can have key value but i am not sure what key to use here.

I verified URL at server which SockJs sends over and it is

```
http://http_backend/cecobrowsega-3.0.0.0.31/sockjs/testapp/620/4ydem52f/xhr?null
```

So in absence of request param its appending a null, seems there is a way to send over request param!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's available in latest sock js client. Discussion here https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/72

we can pass query string along with the connection URL, same syntax as for any HTTP call

Answer (score 2):

For those who needs code sample:

```
  var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost/ws?token=AAA');
  var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
      stompClient.subscribe('/topic/echo', function(data) {
        // topic handler
      });
    }
  }, function(err) {
    // connection error
  });
```

Now all the requests related to websocket will have parameter "?token=AAA"

http://localhost/ws/info?token=AAA&t=1446482506843

http://localhost/ws/515/z45wjz24/websocket?token=AAA

Tested with SockJS 1.0.3

Comment: ok but is it possible to make it dynamic ? i have a ticket that is valid for few seconds so further call need to recalculate the parameter