# Can any other javascript client library, apart from socjjs, be used with spring websocket

Tags: spring-websocket, sockjs

Spring websocket implements SockJs protocol at server and sockjs client can be used to interact with it. Is there any other equivalant library which can be used? We need to send query string with the sockjs comet URL but it seems it is not supported

```
http://sockjs-tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html
https://twitter.com/majek04/status/376371451005128704
```

So, more precisely, is there an alternative to sockjs client which supports query string and the goodness of sockjs client -fallback options?

I have raised a question about support for query string in sockjs:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118456/can-i-add-request-parameter-to-sockjs-constructor-so-that-it-can-be-send-to-serv
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answer of your other question states, yes, this is supported in SocksJS 1.0.0.

And SockJS 1.0.0 will be the default version in Spring Framework 4.2.0.RELEASE, see [SPR-12422](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12422).